# Setup GUI via ssh

Tags: ssh, remote, gui, remote-desktop

I can connect to my universitys server, where I have a virtual machine running on Debian 8.3 (as far as I can see, no additional software is installed yet). I have admin rights and can install new software. Working with ssh isn't a problem. But besides using the shell I'd appreciate having a GUI (like when using RPD, x2go, etc.).
I already read about VPS, would this do the job?

Is there an easy/fast way to get a working desktop GUI with ssh and using it remotely?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: GUI applications would suffice, although the whole desktop would be preferable. I'm using PuTTY and Xming. Everything works fine till now with the approach presented bei @anantary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using **SSH X11-Redirection**.

> man ssh

has this to say about it:

> -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.
>
> X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for
>   the user's X authorization database) can access the local
>   X11 display through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able to perform activities such as keystroke
>   monitoring.
>
> For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh
>   -Y option and the ForwardX11Trusted directive in
>                ssh_config(5) for more information.

Try the following:

> ssh -X yourusername@yourhostname xclock

If this works you can be sure that X11-Redirection works, **given xclock is available** in the system you're accessing via X11.

Now you can just replace **xclock** with the command for the program you actually want to run.

Comment: @drewbenn, thanks. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.
As a note for Windows users: You need a PC X Window Server like Xming to display the apllication

Comment: @byteRider I'm glad, please mark the question as answered.